# woocommerce - removing grid and list views

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

In my woocommerce shop users are able to sort product categories by default, list and grid view.

This is causing a lot of duplicate content.

I'm looking to remove the list and grid view functionality altogether, not simply hide it with `display:none;` as my themes support told me.

[image: clickable filters example for different views]

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this to your functions.php file:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_catalog_ordering', 30 );
```

Comment: This removes the sorting widget instead of the view options

Answer (score 0):

First check if you have this plugin in your site "**WooCommerce Grid / List toggle**" then simply **disable** it through plugin menu.
If you don't have then please give me more detail about which theme or plugin
you are used.