# How to disable the other views in a products page woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

In WooCommerce when I select a particular brand, there are different options like list-view, grid view, grid extended view, and list small view. How do I disable the other view except for the grid view in the brand product page as shown below in the image and need to remove the highlighted one on the image:

[image]

I tried the following code in my theme's `functions.php` file:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_catalog_ordering', 30 );
```

as shown in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37426733)

How do I solve this?

Comment: This behavior doesn't exist by default in WooCommerce and it's due to your theme customization, so you need to look in your theme's files source code to find out how to remove that.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it is customized code and to check whether it is done based on hooks or by changing files, you need to perform an operation where you need to remove every hook one by one associated with that page.

This is the [visual hook guide](https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-archiveshopcat-page/) where you find all the hooks associated with the shop page.

If it is not based on hooks then you need to perform a manual search on theme files to find the actual file associated with that section.

Hope above comment make sense.